# Animate texture drawn in a rectangle in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-animation

I have been learning libGDX for the past two weeks and struggling to get to grips with how to use a texture to animate movement.

Here is how I create my image:

```
Rectangle monkey;

public void create() {
    monkeyImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/monkey.png"));

    monkey = new Rectangle();
    monkey.x = 800 / 2 - 64 / 2;
    monkey.y = 20;
    monkey.width = 128;
    monkey.height = 256;
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(monkeyImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);
    batch.end();
}
```

My texture is two images side by side, each image is 128 * 256 pixels, so the texture size is 256 * 512 pixels. I want to animate the rectangle so it flickers between the two images. I have researched this but cannot get anything to work as I cannot find an example that does this using a rectangle. Is it possible to do what I want, using a rectangle to hold an animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to break your `Texture` in two separately renderable parts.  Use a [`TextureRegion`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html) to reference part of a `Texture`.  Then pass the right `TextureRegion` to `draw`.  In your setup you do something like this:

```
monkeyImage = new Texture(...)
monkeyL = new TextureRegion(monkeyImage, 0, 0, 128, 256);
monkeyR = new TextureRegion(monkeyImage, 128, 0, 128, 256);
```

And in your `render` method:

```
TextureRegion t = someTest ? monkeyL : monkeyR;
batch.draw(t, bucket.x, bucket.y);
```

If you are going to have lots of images for one character, you should look at the Libgdx [`Animation`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html) which is designed to keep track of multiple "key frames" that represent the images used in a timed animation.